# Android ListView custom layout

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in my Activity and for each row Im using my custom layout with a TextView and two Buttons. When I click any of these two buttons, I want a certain action to be performed. In my ArrayAdapter, in getView method, I set onClickListeners to these two buttons.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.process_row, null);
    }


    final Button processCheck = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.processCheck);
    processCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (process.isChecked() == false) {
                process.setChecked(true);
                processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            else {
                process.setChecked(false);
                processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

ArrayList holds objects of mz custom Class Process and process in the code is an instance of  this class. So now when I click this button in one of the ListView rows, I would expect to change the boolean variable in the given Process instance and change the color of the button. That happens, but not only with this one row, but some 3-4 more. So after clicking, I have some 5 changed buttons instead of one. Do you know what im doing wrong here? Note that I dont know the ListActivity coding very well, most of the code is actually copied and edited a little bit from an example file. Thanks!

EDIT:

The problem is probably only with the layout somewhere. When I click the button, more of them change color but only the Process where i clicked has its boolean value changed.

Comment: http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/770/create-custom-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*edit: Find an "out of the box" example at the end of the post!*

Because you see multiple rows affected I guess it has something to do how the system recycles resources and maybe the reference to the `Button` is ambiguous.

I'm not sure where I picked up this practise (either Android Tutorials or our former developer who learned android via these tutorials). However the suggestion is to use a nested class `ViewHolder`

```
private static class ViewHolder {

    public Button processCheck;
}
```

Place this in the Adapter or whatever class your `getView()` is declared in and modify it as such:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    $ViewHolder viewHolder; //wait for the magic!
    if (v == null) {
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.process_row, null);
        $viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        $viewHolder.processCheck = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.processCheck);
        $v.setTag(viewHolder);
        //ok we somewhat stuffed an object with the Button into our View... so what?
    }

    $viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    //see explanation below

    $viewHolder.processCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //set the onClickListener for this and only this button.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (process.isChecked() == false) {
                process.setChecked(true);
                processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            else {
                process.setChecked(false);
                processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

(I marked changes with $. I think this way they should be easy to spot if I use eclipse. Otherwise Find+Replace ^^)

So [getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29) will return an Object associated with the view called on. Object is so incredible generic you can call it to the ViewHolder object you've created. Therefore you can reference the button and store it in the object.
Now whenever you get a ListView you can retrieve the Object and set the `OnclickListener` fresh and new. This way you're only one Listener is called.

Notice that you don't have to call `v.setTag();` again to "save" your changes.

A pitfall might be if you do crazy stuff like inflating different layout in the same list for what reason ever. You might be tempted to assign different `ViewHandlers` to them like:

```
if (v == null) {
    if( someCriteria) {
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.process_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(); 
    }
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.process_another_row, null);
        viewHolder = new AnotherViewHolder(); 
}
```

Then an unchecked call of `getView()` to one ViewHolder or another will likely throw an error at runtime!

Comment: I am eager to try this, but in the onClickListener i get "cant be resolved" for the processCheck. I tought that maybe there should be viewHolder.processCheck instead but when I do this, i get "cant refer to a non-final variable viewHolder". So I change the instance of viewHolder to be final, but I get "may already have been assigned" at the v.getTag() line. Its probably just a stupid problem somewhere, but I cant see it...

Comment: I'll dig into it :) give me some minutes though =)

Comment: One more thing, I had to declare the ViewHandler just as a class, not private static. It would only permit public abstract and final :)

Comment: Sorry for the "couple of minutes". Hopefully the "little somewhat" I coded can demonstrate how the technique is intended to be used. Also notice that even though a high number of items is in the list it still scrolls smoothly. I actually doubt that vandzi's solution will perform so well. I can remember a Google IO talk where the Android team stated one more time that reusing layouts is much more preferable than inflating new ones (which apparently is quite an expensive operation)

Comment: Thanks for your time :) The example you posted looks great, i think ill get it running with it, but I dont have time right now :( anyway, thanks, Ill leave a reply here how it turned out :)

Comment: Well, it still didnt help :( I edited my code to work in the same way as the example code, but still bad...I made a few Log.v instructions to control whats going on. And this is what I found out: By clicking the button, I change bool variable both in my custom class and in my ViewHolder. I change the text in my TextView  and it looks good. But when i scroll down and up, Log.v in my getView function shows good values, but the text in TextView is back to default :(

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the bug and tried to fix is last night. Will update it later to show how I solved it. But good to hear you already could solve it. If you feel like it fork the project to show your solution :)

Comment: I created a new branch where I uplifted `counter` in the `customObject`. The state belongs to the list entry (in this case `customObject` itself. The `ViewHolder` is attached to the recycled `View` so it's a bad place to store item data there. I branched out so it's easy to spot the difference when just running it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.process_row, null);
    }
```

It's because View v is created only for visible items and then it's reused. So just delete ifv==null) so your code will be

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

        v = li.inflate(R.layout.process_row, null);



    final Button processCheck = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.processCheck);
    processCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (process.isChecked() == false) {
                process.setChecked(true);
                processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            else {
                process.setChecked(false);
                processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Comment: This did it :) Only one button change its color but now when I click it and see it change, than scroll down and up again, its color is as it was before clicking :)

Comment: getView is called every time when list is rendered. So you should add into your gerview

Comment: I'm wondering how this will perform when you scroll fast through a list. Inflating all these layouts makes androids crying, not?:C

Answer (score 0):

getView is called every time when list is rendered. So you should add into your gerview condition for setting color:                   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
View v = convertView;

    v = li.inflate(R.layout.process_row, null);
```

//add these lines bellow

if (process.isChecked() == false) {

```
        processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else {

        processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

final Button processCheck = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.processCheck);
processCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (process.isChecked() == false) {
            process.setChecked(true);
            processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else {
            process.setChecked(false);
            processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }

    }
});

return v;
```

}

Comment: I edited the code. All buttons are now blue as they should be, bu again, when I press the button, it goes red, but after scrolling down so I cant see it and than returning back, it is blue again :(

Comment: I wrote it wrong. Write something like this: final Button processCheck = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.processCheck);    if (process.isChecked() == false) {
            processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else {
            processCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }

Comment: I guess process is your adapter

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it:

In my Adapter, I created class:

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    public Button       processCheck;
    public Process      process;
    public TextView     name;
}
```

Than I created a custom listener for my button:

```
private class CustomListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    public ViewHolder   viewHolder;

    public CustomListener(ViewHolder holder) {
        this.viewHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        if (viewHolder.process.isChecked()) {
            viewHolder.name.setText("not checked");
            viewHolder.process.setChecked(false);               
        }
        else {
            viewHolder.name.setText("checked");
            viewHolder.process.setChecked(true);                
        }           
    }
}
```

And my getView function:

```
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if ( convertView == null ) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.process_row, null );

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.processCheck = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.processCheck);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.processName);            
        convertView.setTag( viewHolder );
    }


    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    viewHolder.process = list.get(position);

    if (viewHolder.process.isChecked()) {
        viewHolder.name.setText("checked");         
    } 
    else {
        viewHolder.name.setText("not checked");         
    }       

    CustomListener listener = new CustomListener( viewHolder );
    viewHolder.processCheck.setOnClickListener(listener);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: The problem was with the if-else conditions in getView. After adding them and doing it correctly, the code works. Thanks again, guys :)